Celery: attach custom logger to default celery handler (logfile)
I would like to have a logger that can be used both in django and in celery.
When used by django it should print to console, while when used from a celery task, I would like it to output using the default celery handler (in my case, it dumps to a file specified by the --logfile cmd line argument).
This is especially useful for helper functions that are used by both the django server and celery tasks.
This is what I have in my settings.py file:
LOGLEVEL = os.environ.get("LOGLEVEL", "info").upper()
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,  # the dictConfig format version
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,  # retain the default loggers
    "handlers": {
        # console logs to stderr
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "verbose",
        },
        "django.server": DEFAULT_LOGGING["handlers"]["django.server"],
    },
    "formatters": {
        "verbose": {
            "format": "[{asctime}]|{levelname}| {message}",
            "style": "{",
        },
        "django.server": {
            # "()": "django.utils.log.ServerFormatter",
            "format": "[{asctime}]|{levelname}| {message}",
            "style": "{",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        # default for all undefined Python modules
        "": {
            "level": "WARNING",
            "handlers": ["console"],
        },
        # Our application code
        "app": {
            "level": LOGLEVEL,
            "handlers": ["console"],
            # Avoid double logging because of root logger
            "propagate": False,
        },
        # Default runserver request logging
        "django.server": DEFAULT_LOGGING["loggers"]["django.server"],
        "django.channels.server": DEFAULT_LOGGING["loggers"]["django.server"],
    },
}

In my "app" logger, I have only the console handler for now.
If I define a logger like this:
logger = get_task_logger("app").getChild(__name__)

The output goes to the console, but not to the logfile.
If I define a logger like this instead:
logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

The output goes to the logfile, but not to the console.
I would like, somehow, to add the default celery handler, which I think is created/setup here, to my "app" logger.
Is this possible?

If you want to add the handler specifically to your package namespace (assuming __name__ is simply app, or whatever namespace for your package), just go and add the desired Formatter to the logging handler as you'd normally? Or take a look around and see if this thread might be of use.

that's not what I'm looking for. It's not about the formatter, it's the handler. By default, celery write tasks' output to a file if --logfile is provided. The problem is that if I use that logger without celery (django server or a script), I don't see any output to console, unless I put the logger under "app". But then it won't work with celery.

Just to be clear, setting up the handler still requires the same approach,  You should be naming your logger under your package. Under normal, co-operative usage of the logging module, logging handlers are set up at the entry point of any given application - the entry point should decide which logger names need to have handlers attached (which includes the formatter). Do refer to this thread for Django + Celery logging, and why getLogger(__name__) is standard - do refer to their related threads.
